# How to Edit gridview rows only for last date?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, datagridview

I have a gridview. i want to only make editable those rows which user has edited yesterday.For today user can not edit any row saved yesterday.

Code:

```
Protected Sub btnEdit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEdit.Click     
   EditRow()
End Sub
```

Comment: If you have last modified date time for the records then enable and disable the Edit buttons using record last modified date for each row in RowDataBound event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
Datagridview1.DataSource = /*DataForm Table Containing all Entries*/
DateTime VarLastDate = new DateTime();
VarLastDate = /* yesterDay  Date*/;
Datagridview1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().ToList().Where(w => (DateTime)w.Cells[""].Value  == VarLastDate).ToList().ForEach(f => f.ReadOnly = true);
```

Comment: How to find dates till yesterday@Co. Aden

Comment: from the data you storing as a datasource